# Steering behaviours that gaurentee not to hit something

Tags: ai, steering-behaviors

I'm really struggling how people make steering behaviours that guarantee a given agent will never hit something.

I want to have a flocking algorithm that the agents can follow each other and also avoid each other and avoid objects in the game.

I know how to detect and find a vector for them to change course, but not how to guarantee they adjust in time to make the change before crashing into the object.

Whats the correct way to approach this stuff?

Comment: If the obstacle can move, then a guarantee is tricky — your confidence in avoiding the obstacle is only as good as your prediction of how it will move. But for static obstacles you have only your own (known) movement to factor in. So, what can you tell us about the movement algorithm these agents are using?

Comment: Well currently i give them a constant acceleration. 

Each frame that have some given speed as a scalar, i move the agent along its forward axis by this scalar. And i also have a turn speed in deg/s^-1 which rotates the forward axis towards a given direction.

I opted not to use forces because that was more difficult to work out how to control movement to avoid things.